# Inserting an object into a list on a mongoDB collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection created with the below schema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Name: String,
    email: String,
    music: Array
});


var User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

However, i am having issue inserting the object below into the music array

```
  var newMusic = {
      artist: "Rihanna",
      title: "Believe It"
    };
```

Below is the code i am running to insert the above into the music array

```
 User.update({
      _id: req.user._id
    }, {
      $push: {
        music: newMusic
      }
    });
```

No error message, just not updating the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The below code works

```
User.update({
      _id: req.user._id
    }, {
      $push: {
        music: newMusic
      }
    }).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
```